# trigger event on selected option

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to trigger an event on selected option without submitting form?

```
  <h3 id="center" align="center">OUR SITE CAN ONLY PROVIDE YOU INFO ABOUT MANTIONED COUNTRIES</h3>

<SELECT style="padding:10px;margin-left: 550px;margin-top: 20px;">
    <option name="india">India</OPTION>
    <option name="pakistan">Pakistan</OPTION>
    <option name="US">UNITED STATE</OPTION>
    <option name="UK">UNITED KINGDOM</option>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: No you can't do this in PHP, but you can using Javascript.

Comment: can provide link or method to do that?

Comment: You can write a php function to do this, but if you dont want a page refresh (eg form submit) you will need to call this function via javascript(ajax). Unless the function needs to access sensitive data it would make more sense to write the whole thing in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with PHP (since it's server side language). Use js/jQuery for that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dropdown").change(function() {
    alert("Selection: " + $("option:selected", this).val() + ":" + $("option:selected", this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="center" align="center">OUR SITE CAN ONLY PROVIDE YOU INFO ABOUT MANTIONED COUNTRIES</h3>

<select id="dropdown" name="countries" style="padding:10px;margin-left: 550px;margin-top: 20px;">
  <option value="india">India</option>
  <option value="pakistan">Pakistan</option>
  <option value="US">UNITED STATE</option>
  <option value="UK">UNITED KINGDOM</option>
</select>
```

Also, `name` attribute is for `select` not for `option`. Check snippet markup changed.

Answer (score 2):

you cant do that with php but can be done using Javascript/Jquery as @S.Pols said

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on("change","#select",function(){  // select is the id of your select tag
        alert("selected");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you requested for a javascript example. Here is an example of a javascript variant.

```
<select onchange="jsFunction(this)">
  <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">Label</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<script>
    function jsFunction(select)
    {
      alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
    }
</script>
```